# Populating dynamically created div's using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to output the ajax response from a form submission to a particular div. The form is dynamically generated buttons with data from mysql as values and for each button generated there is also a div created for the result like this.

```
Example form id's:  
id="form1"
id="form2"
id="form3"
id="form4"

div id's:
<div class="res" id="result1">Display form1 data</div>
<div class="res" id="result2">Display form2 data</div>
<div class="res" id="result3">Display form3 data</div>
<div class="res" id="result4">Display form4 data</div>
```

Here is my example form. $count is incrementing the id "form" inside a while loop.

```
echo '<form name="v" action="test.php" value="' . $row['data'] . '" method="post" id="form' . $count . '"><input name="v" type="hidden" value="' . $row['data'] . '"><input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"></form>';
```

I can get this to work but it will fill all of the divs with the success response from clicking the submit buttons if I just use ".res" for the class which is why I need the unique id's using the incremented numbers from $count.  I am unsure how to achieve to this though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("submit", "#form", function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();        
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            dataType: "text",
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $(".res").html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occurred.');
        }
        });        
    });
});
```

Could somebody help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the form tag with an data attribute, containing the target div.

```
echo '<form name="v" action="test.php" value="' . $row['data'] . '" method="post" id="form' . $count . '" data-target="result' . $count . '">...';
```

and later inside your ajax success function, do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("submit", "form[data-target]", function(event)
    {
        var $target = $('#' + $(this).data('target'));
        event.preventDefault();        
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            type: $(this).attr("method"),
            dataType: "text",
            data: new FormData(this),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        success: function(data, status) {
            $target.html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('An error occurred.');
        }
        });        
    });
});
```

Comment: This does not handle the duplicate IDs on the forms

Comment: @mplungjan I applied a small change to get rid of the "duplicate form id" problem

Answer (score 0):

IDs need to be unique so instead do

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = this.id; // form1, form2 etc
  ....
```

or

```
$(document).on("submit", "form[name='v']", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = this.id; // form1, form2 etc
  ....
```

and then

```
  $("#"+id.replace("form","result")).html(data); // result1, result2 etc
```

OR use a data attribute on the form:

```
echo "<form data-id='result".$count."' ....>
```

and have

```
$(document).on("submit", "form[name='v']", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data("id"); // result1, result2 etc
  ....
```

and then

```
  $("#"+id).html(data); // result1, result2 etc
```

Comment: It is more complete than the accepted answer in my opinion - it handles the forms without the ID since you seem to have duplicate IDs

Comment: Honestly it was hard to choose and you did reply first as well and give a lot of usefull information that I do appreciate but since I just copied and pasted the other guys code and made a few small changes I accepted his.

Comment: Hmm right. So I was in fact punished by giving more than one suggestion depending on your needs. No matter. Enjoy

Comment: No not at all and his code does take care of the duplicate id issue because the forms and divs are ran through a loop and assigned incrementing id's and it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that `.each()` provides a counter variable:

```
$("form").each(function (i) {
    $(this).on("submit", function () {
    // ...

    // in the ajax success callback:
    $(".res").eq(i).html(data);
```

Comment: That is rather fragile and prone to errors if the forms needs to target other divs

Comment: True, but it's easy to make it more robust. I'm just showing that this method exists, not an ideal solution.